# Meteor browser-policy local camera not allowed

Tags: meteor, content-security-policy

I'm using Uploadcare to upload images and files in my application and am also using the browser-policy package for content security.  I noticed recently that the camera upload feature was not working and couldn't figure out how to allow it.

> Refused to load media from 'blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/e44633a7-227f-40e2-a3bd-9efd211f677d' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'self' (My Allowed Origins ...) ". Note that 'media-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

It seems the only way I've been able to get this to work is by using:
`BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll('blob:');`

Is there a better way?  It looks like I'm getting an `'unsafe-eval' blob:` warning using the current method. Things I've tried already:
`BrowserPolicy.content.allowDataUrlForAll();`
`BrowserPolicy.content.allowBlobDataUrl();` Not valid
`BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll('blob:http://localhost3000*');`
`BrowserPolicy.content.allowOriginForAll('http://localhost3000*');`

Comment: I deleted my answer because it was inaccurate

Comment: @EliezerSteinbock Thanks for trying!  I updated my question to show that I've tried you suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We use this policy in our package:

`BrowserPolicy.content.allowImageOrigin("blob:");
var constructedCsp = BrowserPolicy.content._constructCsp();
BrowserPolicy.content.setPolicy(constructedCsp +" media-src blob:;");`

If you just want to plug and play it's here: https://github.com/smalljoys/meteor-uploadcare